# Calling JQuery event as function from elsewhere in code...?

Tags: javascript, html, function, jquery

Okay, pretty straight forward JQuery question that I am struggling to find an answer for:

I have a JQuery event that is called on button click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        resetForms('reservation');
        $('#form-reservation').submit(function(event){ 
            event.preventDefault();  //the page will no longer refresh on form submit.
            var resCheck = $(this).find('input[class="reservationid"]').val(); //now we have the reservation ID, let's perform our check.
            document.cancel_res.cancel_agree.checked = false;
            //document.cancel_res.cancel_agree.disabled = false;
            document.cancel_res.cancel_button.disabled=true;
            document.form_reservation.search_button.value="Searching...";
            document.form_reservation.search_button.disabled=true;
            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'inc/searchres.php', 
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'resid='+resCheck, 
                success: function(data){  //data is all the info being returned from the php file 
                    resetForms('reservation');  //clear forms
                    document.form_reservation.search_button.value="Search Reservation";
                    document.form_reservation.search_button.disabled=false;
                    $('#reservation-id').val(resCheck);  //add read ID back into text box
                    var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
                    //BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

The function works perfectly... however, is there anyway to call this function without utilizing the submit event?  I tried to take out everything after the `$('#form-reservation').submit(function(event){`  call and place it in a separate function, and then call the function from the submit event.  However, for whatever reason, this failed.

Basically, I want the submit event to still trigger this function, but I also want to be able to call the entire function under other circumstances.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are developing this in Firefox I would strongly encourage you to install Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) it will give you a better idea of why JavaScript is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply trigger the handler.

```
$("#form-reservation").triggerHandler("submit");
```

http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/

As per the api docs, this does not cause the form to submit, it just run's the handlers bound to that event.

Comment: This was nice and easy and didnt require any change of my code... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's actually pretty easy:

```
var MyFunc = function(event){ 
            typeof event !== 'undefined' ? event.preventDefault() : false;  //the page will no longer refresh on form submit.
            var resCheck = $(this).find('input[class="reservationid"]').val(); //now we have the reservation ID, let's perform our check.
            document.cancel_res.cancel_agree.checked = false;
            //document.cancel_res.cancel_agree.disabled = false;
            document.cancel_res.cancel_button.disabled=true;
            document.form_reservation.search_button.value="Searching...";
            document.form_reservation.search_button.disabled=true;
            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'inc/searchres.php', 
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'resid='+resCheck, 
                success: function(data){  //data is all the info being returned from the php file 
                    resetForms('reservation');  //clear forms
                    document.form_reservation.search_button.value="Search Reservation";
                    document.form_reservation.search_button.disabled=false;
                    $('#reservation-id').val(resCheck);  //add read ID back into text box
                    var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
                    //BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH
                }
            }

$(document).ready(function(){
        resetForms('reservation');
        $('#form-reservation').submit(MyFunc); //this calls on submit
    });

//this calls without need of a submit
MyFunc();
```

Comment: Made a slight modification here - only running `preventDefault` if event isn't undefined. That should take care of any errors of calling MyFunc outside of the submit scope.

Comment: `MyFunc(event)` should be `MyFunc`

Comment: Where, in the submit? You have to provide the event to the function scope - so you need to pass event. If you don't provide an argument in submit(MyFunc(event)) then event will be typeof = 'undefined'.

Comment: Kevin is right, the .submit() method is taking as an argument the MyFunc function as a parameter, not actually calling it.  the event object will be passed when the submit event is fired

Comment: I don't have the authority (from StackOverflow), Looks like Gus was more patient :P

Comment: I agree with @KevinB; as far as I know, this would evaluate `MyFunc` on the `ready` event and not on the `submit` sinc you're pretty much *calling* the function. I'd say use the `.submit([eventData], [callback])` signature instead

Comment: I like your idea of using the callback, but I'm iffy on which event listeners provide or evaluate callbacks, so I used a plain-jane approach.